# How to extrude with another material applied to extruded mesh?

Tags: materials, uv, extrude

Is there a way to use material that i want for extruded mesh? I use different UVs so assigning another material after extrusion is inconvenient for me. Thanks in advance.
[image: screenshot that shows the problem]

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do that.  Extrusion always applies the material from the starting mesh.  The best I know, as I'm sure you do, is immediately after the extrusion while it's still selected, select the new material and click Assign.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how it works